# Security on Acuator endpoints unintentionally disabled

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I have an application with a pretty simple security configuration and can't seem to secure the Actuator endpoints. From what I've read elsewhere on SO, it seems like it shouldn't be simple to disable security for these endpoints so I'm puzzled and would appreciate some help in understanding what's off here.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private WebSecurityProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(0)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private WebSecurityProperties properties;

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/web/**", "/example/**").hasRole(properties.getApiUserGroup())
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private WebSecurityProperties properties;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/index.html")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/**").hasRole(properties.getAdminGroup());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like I had a couple of issues with my configuration.

- Use of @EnableWebSecurity annotation. Apparently this disables the Spring Boot defaults. According to [dsyer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/179), "If you use @EnableWebSecurity you switch off the Spring Boot settings completely"
- Failure to specify [order of the configuration application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-actuator). Specifically, I did not declare `@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)` at the class level.

As part of my effort to get this working, I simplified my configuration and ended up with this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private WebSecurityProperties properties;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource);
   }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/web/**", "/example/**").hasRole(properties.getApiUserGroup())
                .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll().and()
            .httpBasic().realmName("API example");
    }
}
```